# req.body is empty and I can't figure out why

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to express and node and I'm trying to make an axios post to my server but the req.body is coming up empty when I console.log in node. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm console logging and sending to postman.

Here is server.js

```
const app = require('express')()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  res.send('hello')
})

const port = 4444;

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
      console.log('body: ', req.body)
      res.status(200).send(req.body)
});



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on port 4444');
});
```

My axios call

```
export default class Form extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props) 
         this.state = {
            name: 'kaleb',
            message: '',
            email: '',
            number: '',
            sent: false
         }




     }

     handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })

     }

     handleSubmit = () => {
         axios.post("/send", {name: this.state.name}).then(() => {
             console.log(this.state.name)
         })


     }
```

Comment: request is sent through `axios` above or postman? any error in network tab or console? above code looks fine

Comment: sent through `axios` no errors in console. I'm stumped

Comment: are you seeing your console.log in handleSubmit()??

Comment: Yes I am seeing it

Comment: It is getting through, so is it something in my server?

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/*+json'})); //in server.js

Comment: This looks like missing CORS handling. Especially if it's working in postman (because postman does not care about CORS). There should be an error in your browser console, make sure you are not filtering anything out. (Enable verbose level)

Comment: It is not working in postman either.

Comment: Oh my bad. Still you are going to need it for cross-port POST requests. I would then try adding a  `.catch(console.error)` to your axios call

Comment: and then try a express wildcard route `app.all('*', (req,res)=>{ ... })` to make sure you are not missing anything. like a OPTIONS request :PP (back to cors, sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the url as `http://localhost:4444/send` in your axios call:

```
 handleSubmit = () => {
         axios.post("http://localhost:4444/send", {name: this.state.name}).then(() => {
             console.log(this.state.name)
         })
```

Comment: This worked after I added cors to my express server. I just need to add a proxy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this
In server.js:

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/*+json'}));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));//or true whatever you need
```

axios call:

```
    axios({method:'post',url:'/send',data:{name:this.state.name}})
      .then(console.log(this.state.name));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working. Not sure what else to try

Comment: are you seeing anything from your server ?

Comment: When I press submit for my axios call nothing happens in my server, but when I hit it with postman it shows `body: {}`

Comment: I'm also not really sure why you are using postman, why not just take it out of the chain? It looks like you have a front/and backend.

Comment: Well choose one to debug at a time, postman is supposed to emulate a front end, it's point less if you have a front end. It sounds like postman is getting through then so it must just be a matter of setting up postman differently. Where are you entering your form data in postman.

Comment: i would need to see the rest of the form to help figure out why your react app is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here's what I think after read all of the above comments.

1. You said, when you send the request via postman it's console.log an empty req.body. So there's no problem with your URL. It's heading to correct router. Postman have 3 content types. Just select  "X-www-form-urlencoded" & send the request again. It should work.
2. In your component, You said nothing happen after submit. Most probably the problem should be with your URL. Your backend server runs on PORT 4444 & usually react app run on PORT 3000. So when you call axios.post('/send') it's actually sent to `localhost:3000/server` instead of `localhost:4444/server`. Now it will not work. You need to set up a proxy to avoid this problem. Here's the way https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development. Or you can just use `axios.post('http://localhost:4444/server')`

Note: *if you use `axios.post('http://localhost:4444/server')`, you will face to the cors issue. Use this to eliminate that issue https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors*

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by setting the urlencoded extension to true, try this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```